# To load the very previous page after closing the modal

Tags: angularjs, jsp, angular-ui-router

I am new to angularjs and i have created page with two links
1)For Modal popup
2)Is a jsp page
And my issue is how i can load the very previous page after closing of the modal popup opened.
Now it is directly going back to the home or index page. I want it to go back to the previous where the modal popup was invoked?
Can any one help me to overcome this?
And thanks in advance
Code is written below
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="css/style.css"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.11/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>

    // init the app with ui.router and ui.bootstrap modules
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

    // make back button handle closing the modal
    app.run(['$rootScope', '$modalStack',
      function($rootScope, $modalStack) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
          var top = $modalStack.getTop();
          if (top) {
            $modalStack.dismiss(top.key);
          }
        });
      }
    ]);

    // configure the stateProvider
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // default page to be "/" (home)
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        // configure the route states
        $stateProvider

          // define home route "/"
          .state('home', {
            url: '/'
          })
          .state('profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl:'newjsp2.jsp'
          })

          // define modal route "/modal"
          .state('modal', {
            url: '/modals',

            // trigger the modal to open when this route is active
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal',
              function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
                $modal

                  // handle modal open
                  .open({
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl: 'modalwindow.jsp',
                    backdrop: false,
                    controller: ['$scope',
                      function($scope) {

                        // handle after clicking Cancel button
                        $scope.cancelModal = function() {
                          $scope.$dismiss();
                        };
                        // close modal after clicking OK button
                        $scope.ok = function() {
                          $scope.$close(true);
                        };
                      },

                    ]
                  })

                  // change route after modal result
                  .result.then(function() {
                    // change route after clicking OK button
                    $state.transitionTo('home');
                  }, function() {
                    // change route after clicking Cancel button or clicking background
                    $state.transitionTo('home');
                  });

              }
            ]

          })
          .state('modals', {
            url: '/modals2',
            modal:true,
            // trigger the modal to open when this route is active
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal',
              function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
                $modal

                  // handle modal open
                  .open({
                    templateUrl: 'modalwindow2.jsp',
                    backdrop: false,
                    controller: ['$scope',
                      function($scope,$state) {
                        // handle after clicking Cancel button
                        $scope.cancelModal = function() {
                          $scope.$dismiss();

                        };
                        // close modal after clicking OK button
                        $scope.ok = function() {
                          $scope.$close(true);
                        };
                      },

                    ]
                  })

                  // change route after modal result
                  .result.then(function() {
                    // change route after clicking OK button

                    $state.transitionTo('home');
                  }, function() {
                    // change route after clicking Cancel button or clicking background
                    $state.transitionTo('profile');
                  });

              }
            ]

          });
      }
    ])
    .run(function($rootScope, $location, $state) {
  $rootScope.$location = $location;
  alert(location)
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
  </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: chocolate">

    <a href="#/modals" class="btn btn-default">POPUP---->1</a>
    <a href="#/modals2" class="btn btn-default">POPUP-->2</a>
    <a href="#/profile" class="btn btn-default">Profile!</a>

  <div ui-view></div>

</body>
<style>
     .modal-dialog{
          width: 100% !important;
          margin: 0px !important;
      }
      .modal-body{
          padding-bottom:488px;
      }
</style>
</html>
```

'

Comment: Please provide actual code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Added the code,

Comment: I do have one more doubt,Is there any way to remember the values within field while returning to previous page on closing the modal popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

Inside your `enter` functions I added `var previous = $state.current.name;` and then changed `$state.transitionTo(...);` to `$state.transitionTo(previous);`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="css/style.css"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.11/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>

    // init the app with ui.router and ui.bootstrap modules
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

    // make back button handle closing the modal
    app.run(['$rootScope', '$modalStack',
      function($rootScope, $modalStack) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
          var top = $modalStack.getTop();
          if (top) {
            $modalStack.dismiss(top.key);
          }
        });
      }
    ]);

    // configure the stateProvider
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // default page to be "/" (home)
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        // configure the route states
        $stateProvider

          // define home route "/"
          .state('home', {
            url: '/'
          })
          .state('profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl:'newjsp2.jsp'
          })

          // define modal route "/modal"
          .state('modal', {
            url: '/modals',

            // trigger the modal to open when this route is active
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal',
              function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
                var previous = $state.current.name;

                $modal

                  // handle modal open
                  .open({
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl: 'modalwindow.jsp',
                    backdrop: false,
                    controller: ['$scope',
                      function($scope) {

                        // handle after clicking Cancel button
                        $scope.cancelModal = function() {
                          $scope.$dismiss();
                        };
                        // close modal after clicking OK button
                        $scope.ok = function() {
                          $scope.$close(true);
                        };
                      },

                    ]
                  })

                  // change route after modal result
                  .result.then(function() {
                    // change route after clicking OK button
                    $state.transitionTo(previous);
                  }, function() {
                    // change route after clicking Cancel button or clicking background
                    $state.transitionTo(previous);
                  });

              }
            ]

          })
          .state('modals', {
            url: '/modals2',
            modal:true,
            // trigger the modal to open when this route is active
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal',
              function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
                var previous = $state.current.name;

                $modal

                  // handle modal open
                  .open({
                    templateUrl: 'modalwindow2.jsp',
                    backdrop: false,
                    controller: ['$scope',
                      function($scope,$state) {
                        // handle after clicking Cancel button
                        $scope.cancelModal = function() {
                          $scope.$dismiss();

                        };
                        // close modal after clicking OK button
                        $scope.ok = function() {
                          $scope.$close(true);
                        };
                      },

                    ]
                  })

                  // change route after modal result
                  .result.then(function() {
                    // change route after clicking OK button

                    $state.transitionTo(previous);
                  }, function() {
                    // change route after clicking Cancel button or clicking background
                    $state.transitionTo(previous);
                  });

              }
            ]

          });
      }
    ])
    .run(function($rootScope, $location, $state) {
  $rootScope.$location = $location;
  alert(location)
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
  </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: chocolate">

    <a href="#/modals" class="btn btn-default">POPUP---->1</a>
    <a href="#/modals2" class="btn btn-default">POPUP-->2</a>
    <a href="#/profile" class="btn btn-default">Profile!</a>

  <div ui-view></div>

</body>
<style>
     .modal-dialog{
          width: 100% !important;
          margin: 0px !important;
      }
      .modal-body{
          padding-bottom:488px;
      }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: This code worked for me.and thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: i do have one more doubt,Is there any way to remember the values within field while returning to previous page.

Comment: @Rinoy: You're welcome! However, I don't understand what you're asking in your second comment.

Comment: i have some textfield in my form having some typed values in it and when i invoke a modal and there  after closing the modal the field in the previous page seems to be empty,how i can keep the values in the field as it is

Comment: @Rinoy: I think I understand, and I think I have an answer.  However you should ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry man,The website is not allowing me to post a new question

Comment: @Rinoy Here's a way to do it: https://plnkr.co/edit/7HhVHkePR4xLSmPCjhGx?p=preview

Comment: i am not able to get the typed values after closing the modal

Comment: @Rinoy If you can, please make a new question (I understand if you can't).  Secondly, I'm not sure understand what your problem is - are you saying that there are fields on your modal and you're trying to get the value out of those fields once you close the modal?